# How can we disable the datatable export buttons(Or prevent click event) when datatable is empty?

Tags: button, datatables, datatable-buttons

I'm using  [datatable](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html) , I need to disable the export buttons(Excel, PDF) when the grid having the empty rows.
**How can we handle the datatable export buttons click actions?**

I have done the grid initialization as below.
I don't know how to handle the datatable export buttons(PDF, Excel).
Can you please help me how to fix this.

**Update:**

1. And I have one more issue that when user click on the Excel or PDF button then the grid columns width is collapsing.

**I need even user click on the Excel or PDF buttons the grid column width should not change. How can we achieve this?**

2. After exporting the data in to excel, columns are not auto adjusted in the excel.

   **How can we make the columns(After export datatable data into excel) auto adjusted?**

   ```
    var buttonCommon = {
       exportOptions: {
         format: {
           body: function(data, column, row, node) {
             return data;
           }
         }
       }
     };

        var dataTableObj = {
         "processing": true,
         "destroy": true,
         "scrollX": true,
         "columns": [{
           "data": "CollegeName",
           "width":"30%"

         }, {
           "data": "AffiliatedTo",
            "width":"15%"

         }, {
           "data": "TPOName",
           "width":"20%"

         }, {
           "data": "Phone",

         }, {
           "data": "Website",

           "bSortable": false
         }],
         dom: 'lBfrtip',
         buttons: [
         $.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
                   extend: 'excelHtml5',
                     title: 'Colleges',

               } ),


           {
             extend: 'pdf',
             title: 'Colleges'
           }

         ],

         fnRowCallback: function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
            //Some code
           return nRow;
         }


       };


         var dataTbl = $('#tblColleges').DataTable(dataTableObj);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how far following solution makes sense but it was resolved my issue.

> I need to disable the export buttons(Excel, PDF) when the grid having
>   the empty rows. How can we handle the datatable export buttons click
>   actions?

here I have done  with the [datatables](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.action) action property.

```
       buttons: [{
      extend: 'excelHtml5',
      title: 'Colleges',
      action: function(e, dt, button, config) {
        if (this.data().length > 0) {

          $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.excelHtml5.action(e, dt, button, config);
          $scope.hasAlert = 0;
          $scope.$apply();
        } else {
          $scope.hasAlert = 2;
          $scope.alertMsg = __APP_MESSAGE__.GridEmptyMsg;
          $scope.$apply();
        }
      }

    }, {
      extend: 'pdf',
      title: 'Colleges',
      action: function(e, dt, button, config) {
        if (this.data().length > 0) {

          $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.pdfHtml5.action(e, dt, button, config);
          $scope.hasAlert = 0;
          $scope.$apply();
        } else {
          $scope.hasAlert = 2;
          $scope.alertMsg = __APP_MESSAGE__.GridEmptyMsg;
          $scope.$apply();
        }
      }
    },

  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution has worked for me put it in fnDrawCallback function

```
$(tableName).dataTable({

 "fnDrawCallback":function () {
                   var table = $(tableName).DataTable();
                    if (table.data().length === 0)
            table.buttons('.buttons-html5').disable();
                 else
            table.buttons('.buttons-html5').enable();


            } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle the datatable export buttons click actions is to create your own button and **trigger the datatable export button** on the click of your button.
This way you will handle the click actions of your created button:

```
$('#exportBtn').on('click', function () {
  dataTbl.button(0).trigger();
});
```

You can remove `dom: 'lBfrtip'` to hide the original datatable button.